# Compilation error while testing BiConsumer

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have written below method which accept `BiConsumer<Object, Object>`, when I pass the method reference of method `testBiConsumer(String a, String b)` I am getting a compilation error stating:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method biConsumerTest(String, String, BiConsumer<Object,Object>) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, 
     Test::testBiConsumer)
    - The type Test does not define testBiConsumer(Object, Object) that is applicable here
```

If I change BiConsumer from `BiConsumer<Object, Object>` to `BiConsumer<String , String >` it works just fine.

How do I make below code work? I want `public static void biConsumerTest(String a, String b, BiConsumer<String, String> biConsumer)` to be generic.

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Test.biConsumerTest("A", "B", Test::testBiConsumer);
        }

        public static void biConsumerTest(String a, String b, BiConsumer<Object, Object> biConsumer){
            biConsumer.accept(a, b);
        }

        public static void testBiConsumer(String a, String b) {
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks a bit funny and unclear what you *actually* what to achieve, but to make it generic:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.biConsumerTest("A", "B", Test::testBiConsumer);
    }

    public static <T> void biConsumerTest(T a, T b, BiConsumer<T, T> biConsumer) {
        biConsumer.accept(a, b);
    }

    public static <S> void testBiConsumer(S a, S b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `<S>` type parameter on `testBiConsumer` is pointless, it doesn’t add anything compared to the declaration `testBiConsumer(Object a, Object b)`. After changing `biConsumerTest` to the generic declaration `<T> void biConsumerTest(T a, T b, BiConsumer<T, T> biConsumer)` you can even keep the original `testBiConsumer(String a, String b)`, as the compiler can infer `String` for `T` without problems.